# ThreadPool - java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpool

I am getting **java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException** whenever we are getting more calls.

We have defined coreSize as 10 and maximumSize as 25, but we are getting this exception for 10 threads itself.   We should get this exception after 25 threads Right? Am I missing anything ? Could you please help me to fix this ?

```
hystrix.threadpool.servicename.coreSize=10
hystrix.threadpool.servicename.maximumSize=25
```

Exception trace :

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@74132085 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@21e44930[Running, pool size = 10, active threads = 10, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 23666917]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextScheduler$ThreadPoolWorker.schedule(HystrixContextScheduler.java:172)
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextScheduler$HystrixContextSchedulerWorker.schedule(HystrixContextScheduler.java:106)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:50)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:30)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10346)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10442)
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable
```

Answer (score 1):

RejectedExecutionException occurs when the thread pool is not able to accept any new tasks.

If some idle thread is available in the thread pool, it starts task execution immediately. Else the task is queued in a `queue` inside the thread pool. Depending on the thread pool implementation, this queue could be bounded. In such a scenario, when a new task is submitted, since it cannot be queued the thread pool throws RejectedExecutionException.

I don't think you can have unbounded queues in hystrix. You need to determine the appropriate queue size depending on your load in *HystrixThreadPoolProperties*.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `hystrix.threadpool.default.allowMaximumSizeToDivergeFromCoreSize=true` if you want to overide maximumSize